# How to find two edge-disjoint paths for two source-target pairs in graph $G(V,E)$?

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

Suppose $G(V,E)$ is a undirected graph, and $V$ is the set of vertices, $E$ is the set of edges. $r_{s,d}$ represents a path from source vertex $s$ to end target vertex $d$. For distinct vertices $a,b,c,d \in V$, how to judge if there exists two edge-disjoint path $r_{a,b}$ and $r_{c,d}$, which means $$\forall e_1\in r_{a,b}, \forall e_2\in r_{c,d}, e_1 \neq e_2$$, and if exists, how to find one at least?